# How do I optimize my function to get the maximum output?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a very complicated function func which receives two numeric inputs (`x` and `y`) and spits out a numeric output (`z`).

I want to get the maximum value of `z`, subject to constraints for `x` and `y`.

For argument's sake let's say the function is as such: `func(x, y) = x^2 - 2xy`. In actual fact, it is far more complex.

The constraints are:

- `x` must be an integer between and including 1 and 10 i.e. `[1,10]`
- `y` must be one of the following integers: `1, 3, 9, 13, 12, 23`

How do I do this, please? I have been looking at `scipy.optimize.minimize` but cannot figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the function that you want to optimize is not linear, right?

Comment: Yes it is not linear

Comment: Well, if your domain is so small (x in [1..10] and y in [1, 3, 9, 13, 12, 23]), why don't you test all combinations?

Comment: And only the global maximum is important to you, right?

Comment: In actual fact my domain is not so small. I am simply producing a simplified version of my problem here.

Comment: Yes only the global maximum is important

Comment: Can you ever be satisfied that what you found is the global maximum without testing all the points? For a continuous function, you could find an analytical solution, but for a discrete domain, I don't think that applies.

Comment: Another question about the problem: the constraints are linear?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question "the constraints are linear?". The constraints are integers within a range (x) or discrete set (y).

Comment: Not a proper answer, but you can try and follow the scipy guide for the optimize function https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: Just to clarify: x - y^2 < 100 would be an example of a non-linear constraint

Comment: x is bound by a linear constraint. I suppose y is neither linear nor non-linear because it is a randomly selected set of integers.